# How to detect which PHP script is sending SPAM

Tags: apache-2.2, php, email, spam

A php script is sending tons of emails. I want to detect what is the source. All emails are sent by the use www-data which the user used by apache. When I check process, I have this result :

```
www-data 16220  0.7  4.7 402508 95924 ?        S    09:37   0:06 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16352  0.4  3.8 402132 78064 ?        S    09:39   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16725  0.6  3.8 402472 78624 ?        S    09:46   0:02     /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16840  0.8  4.2 410744 87204 ?        S    09:48   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16949  1.0  4.5 417560 93436 ?        S    09:49   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16958  1.0  3.5 402120 72748 ?        S    09:50   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16978  1.2  4.6 425160 94864 ?        S    09:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16980  0.8  3.5 402140 72208 ?        S    09:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16983  0.4  2.6 402160 54400 ?        S    09:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Apache is using many processes and I don't know what is the script that send mail.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Emails have nothing to do with number of Apache processes. Apache just starts several threads to serve requests in parallel...

Comment: @AndreySapegin, I now. But I don't know which script are running.

Comment: @GregL, my question is more precise.

Comment: Your question is about a *particular* aspect of a compromised server. The  advice provided in the referenced question still applies.

Comment: @GregL, yes and I already checked it without success so I'm asking another question for my specific problem.

Comment: The related question could be helpful:  http://serverfault.com/questions/130069/find-the-php-script-thats-sending-mails?rq=1

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, I think you're right. I'm checking it. It does not work for now because sendmail_path seems to be ignored. I ' trying to resolve this bug.

Comment: Run maldet. Delete the malware it finds. Sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do an strace to dump all running Apache processes to a file and then once the spam goes out, see if you can track down what was going on (such as by saving frequent dumps of server-status using mod_status if it's not obvious from the strace by looking at file paths).

You could try something like the following - though note it may be resource intensive.  Adjust the `-s` parameter as needed.

```
pidlist=''; \
for pid in `ps ax | grep apache2 |grep /usr/sbin/apache2 | awk '{print $1}'`;\
    do pidlist="$pidlist -p $pid"; \
done; \
strace -s 1024 -tt -F -f $pidlist  > strace_apache2.out 2>&1
```